# Displaying multiple images from same point in QGIS

Tags: qgis, image, photos

After the dead of eVis plugin I have troubles working on my project in QGIS 3.16:

I have a shapefile with multiple row, each one with the same position: the content is data from archaeological sites and is derived from a query on a spatialite database.
Each row is provided with the path of a picture.

I need to display, in sequence, all the pictures related to the site (with also their data, stored in the single photo row, but that is ok). Until now the eVis browser from eVis plugin was doing exactly this, but now is dead and I cannot find any replacement.

I've tried to work on the Attribute Forms in the layer properties, but I can only manage to do the required task (via Identify Features) when there is only one image related to a single position.
With multiple images the Identify Features open a tree form, with the path of the images but not the pictures. I attach two example screenshots from a test project (single and multi image point).

Any idea on how to resolve the problem?

[image: Multi Pictures]

[image: Single Picture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try showing the attribute table in `form view`, and eventually filtering it to list only visible features (or selected features)

You can show the image using the HTML Widget. In the example below, the (full) path is saved in the field `"a"` and the expression is, on a single line,

```
<script>document.write(expression.evaluate("'<img src=\"' || a  ||'\">'"));</script>
```

To build the path and decorations, you can elaborate such as

```
<script>document.write(expression.evaluate("'<div>Image: <img src = \"file:///'|| photo ||'\"  width=\"300\" height=\"225\" alt=\"Alias Name\"/></div>'"));</script>
```

Please note the 3 slashes for the `file:///`

[image]

Comment: In the attribute table I'm already able to see the images, also without the file:/// at the beginning of the file path. I wonder if it would be possible to click on the points and display all the images related, like was in the eVis browser.

Comment: Some of us are unfamiliar with eVis, so please describe in more detail.

Comment: Have you tried action ? I wonder if it could work when you have sevral points nearby.

Comment: With eVis Browser you just activate the function in the toolbar and then click on the feature on map. The same as Identify Features function. The mask then give you all the information contained in the feature row, included the image provided by the path. BUT, unless Identifiy Features, if there are other feature on the same position you are able to cycle through them in the mask, and vilsualize the information and images.

Comment: About action, I cannot manage to see multiple images in the same position. Action work very well but only for single image point.